# How to build sass files with django

Tags: django, sass

I'm completly new with Django and python (and alone as tech in my company, not able to ask help to previous dev). I have to maintain an existing app written in django still developing new services fully written in node, which is my most important task (and my skills). I have a problem that i have fixed some bugs in UX, fixing CSS mostly. And  I don't understand how to build sass.

In manage.py, when i ask the list of commands the only things which is related to my problem is "collectstatic" which seems to not build but just collect static files (good naming so) in one folder. And obviously, it doesn't resolve my problem.

Any suggestion ? I'm lost in this big new thing. Many love on every body who can help me. Do you know if there is an integrated tool ? Do i need to use an external compiler which is just not documented ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django got nothing to do with compiling assets, you compile it your way in node using your favorite bundler like gulp or webpack and then introduce the final path to django. but people stumbled upon this and created bunch of helper libs, checkout [django_webpack](https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader).

In case you felt overwhelm then save learning curve time and do like I said earlier, bundle it on your flavor and create a management command in Django that you can run the bundler from python context.

Comment: using a basic node-sass it was working. Many thanks !