# Compiling SCSS/SASS in django in production environment?

Tags: css, node.js, django, npm, sass

I'm not an expert in Django, but I was reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70582024/how-to-build-sass-files-with-django) and found that there's not much I can do to compile SASS in production environment. Could you suggest some way to compile SASS/SCSS in production environment? Can node JS and python run simultaneously on VPS so that sass can be compiled?